# How to notify a User whenever an object is Created in Django model

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I would like to tell a user automatically whenever a new game or a movie is uploaded or published on the website.

below is my models.

```
#games model
GAME_TYPE=(
    ("action", "action"),
     ("adventure", "adventure"),
      ("racing", "racing"),
       ("puzzle", "puzzle"),
)
MOV_TYPE=(
    ("action", "action"),
     ("adventure", "adventure"),
      ("sci-fi", "sci-fi"),
       ("horror", "horror"),
       ("drama", "drama"),
)
GAME_OS=(
     ("Windows", "Windows"),
     ("Android", "Android"),
)
class Games(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    type=models.CharField(max_length=40, choices=GAME_TYPE)
    os=models.CharField(max_length=15, choices=GAME_OS)
    img=models.ImageField()
    developer=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    version=models.CharField(max_length=10)
    ratings=models.CharField(max_length=10)
    description=models.TextField()
    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.name
    
    class Movies(models.Model):
        name=models.CharField(max_length=50)
        type=models.CharField(max_length=40, choices=MOV_TYPE)
        description=models.TextField()
        released=models.DateField()
        def __str__(self) -> str:
            return self.name
```

I need direct me on how to create an function to send or notify a user automatically whenever a game is published but l don't know how to do it.

Anyone to solve me

Comment: But am confused, people are letting all my questions concerning this issue to be closed but they are not directing where  l can get the  exact answer. I don't know why. People direct me than voting all my questions to be closed.

Comment: You can use Django’s built-in signals. The post_save signal, for instance, is sent after a model’s save() method is called.

Answer (score 0):

You can use events queue, websocket for that purpose

basic flow with just using DB, you can

- create a `central notification` table and `user notification` table
- whenever a new movie or game is published, create new `central notification` ( if there is specific single user notification, then create `user notification` directly )
- now whenever user login into your system, then fetch all un-fetched `central notification` and insert it into `user notification`( save the last-fetched `central notification` ref in `user notification` so you can pull only un-fetched notification )
- then display all `user notification` records in page

you can use read tag in `user notification` to display unread notification and you'll need one column that stores last pulled notification from `central notification` table

note this is just a basic approach, you can use events queue to store central notification, and websocket to deliver real time notification